# Where does the air enter the passenger cabin?

Tags: aircraft-systems

After passing through the packs and turbines, where does the air get into the cabin? On the 737-800, for example. I don't see on the roof any grill to let the air enter the cabin, look:
[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Norwegian-Air-Shuttle/Boeing-737-8JP/2171237/L/)

Where does the air enter the cabin? According this graphic, the air enters through the roof and exits through the wall:
[image]

Comment: check the floor, that's where the packs are.

Comment: @ratchetfreak You mean the grills on the wall? I asked a question about those and their purpose is cabin air circulation

Comment: "Circulation", ergo where cabin air enters and/or exits

Comment: @kepler22b They said it was for pressure balancing between the cargo compartment and the passenger compartment.
There are those ceiling nozzles above the seat that the air comes in at the least.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'll put a picture to show that the air enters the cabin on the roof and exits through the grills on the wall :)

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Yes. The one who answered my question said that it was for cabin air circulation, though he didn't have any technical reference to say that the grills also provided pressure balancing

Comment: I see a big opening in the ceiling, that's were the air comes from. See [here](http://www.aneta.org/theories/CAPOV/CabinAirFlow.gif) and [here](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/publications/tp185-6531.html). Here a nice [3D view of the ducts](http://www.composite-industrie.com/media/produit/4524688518.jpg), but is focuses on the cockpit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me in your top image that the air vent is right there at the center of the ceiling.

[image]

It looks like a linear slot diffuser running the length of the cabin.  Similar to this
[image]